# R ggplpot(): Thicker X and Y Axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I have data that crosses the x-axis and I am trying to darken the axes to make them more apparent in the chart.  The code I am using just keeps darkening the lines on the bottom and left of the box around the chart and not the axes themselves.  What am I missing?  Code and image are below.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=eff, aes(EaR, Forward.Cost), color=rgb(187,8,38, max=255)) +
  geom_line(data=arbitrary, aes(EaR, Forward.Cost), color=rgb(196,165,96, max=255)) +
  ggtitle("Efficient Frontier \n") +
  labs(x="EaR", y="Forward Cost") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(size = 1, color = rgb(0,0,0,max=255))) +
  geom_point(data=eff, aes(EaR, Forward.Cost),size=2, color=rgb(187,8,38,max=255)) +
  geom_point(data=arbitrary, aes(EaR, Forward.Cost),size=2, color=rgb(196,165,96,max=255))
```

Comment: would simply adding a line work? `geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + geom_vline(xintercept = 0)`

Comment: That works, I just thought there would be a way to do it with the parameters of the ggplot function.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3390169 I don't think you can make true black darker. Since you're already setting the color of the axis to true black that's the darkest it can get unless you want to change its color.

Answer (score 0):

For backgrounds and borders.

```
gg+theme(panel.border = element_rect(linetype = "solid", colour = "black", size=5))+
```

rest of your code

Answer (score 0):

There is [an issue with the argument "panel.border" in ggplot2](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/670).
The users etiennebr and nfdisco have detected that, even when printing in PDF, lines showed discrepancies in thickness between different axes.

Therefore, there seems to be very little workarounds to this persistent issue. You may want to try different values for the line thickness, for `png(res=xxx)`, or `ggsave(dpi=xxx)`, to see if there are any significant changes, as suggested by the collaborator wch.